# Return value in Spring boot framework

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, mobile-application

I have a project using spring boot framework. From what I understand of the current code base the API's are designed in a way to work with the web browser. For Example

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
// Login code
    return "redirect:/home"
}
```

Is it possible to modify this code base to that we return a JSON instead of the redirection? My ultimate goal is to send have a mobile application making the requestion to this endpoint. Is it possible to modify this code base or I have to create a new endpoint for mobile application.

Please excuse me if this sounds like a stupid question. I have no prior experience with spring boot and trying to understand my options

Thank You.

Comment: Have you taken time to read [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-write-a-json-rest-service)?

Comment: Yes, I have reading documentation and going through few tutorials. Just wanted to know if this is even possible and if I am on the correct path. Thank You for replying.

Comment: As stated what does the documentation tell you... The first line I linked to is giving you the answer...

Comment: The problem here is I don't want to break existing code while returning a JSON instead of the redirection.

Comment: Why should it break... Use `@ResponseBody` for the situations you want JSON and let content negotiation together with `@RequestMapping` figure out the right method to call. The Spring Reference guide explains everything you can return from a [request handling method](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-return-types)

Comment: Sure. Thank a lot for the advice. I'll look into it